# How to use ShellExecuteEx() without stealing the focus of the opener window

Tags: winapi

I am trying to open a browser through my application but I do not want it to run in the foreground and steal the focus from my application.

**The code:**

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open";
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"http://www.microsoft.com";
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
    ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}
return 0;
```

In my application, there is a button which is sending the command message to execute the opening code, but my application goes to the background and the browser comes to the foreground.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can let it steal the focus from your app and then programmatically switch back to your app.

Comment: Calling `LockSetForegroundWindow()` before `ShellExecuteEx()` might work?

Comment: Why are you trying to launch a browser with the `SW_HIDE` flag?  In any case, try using `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` instead: "*Displays a window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.*"

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you start the browser using `CreateProcess()` instead and in the `STARTUPINFO` structure you initialize, use `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` in the `dwFlags` and in `wShowWindow`, be sure to include the `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` flag. That should allow the process to start but not become the active window.

Comment: There is no `SW_NOACTIVATE` flag, the actual name is `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` instead.  Which you can also pass to `ShellExecute/Ex()`.  If you use `CreateProcess()`, you have to know the exact path, filename, and parameters of the browser EXE.  `ShellExecute/Ex()` works out those details for you.

Comment: Fair enough, no compiler on the editor :-)   I use CreateProcess b/c ShellExecute will fail if your URL contains an anchor.  Use AssocQueryString and SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate to have the OS build the path for you.